# if $A \subset B \subset X$ then $\mbox{dist}(x,B) \le \mbox{dist}(x,A)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Prove that if $A \subset B \subset X$ then $\mbox{dist}(x,B) \le \mbox{dist}(x,A)$.

My attempt (by contradiction) :

Suppose that $\mbox{dist}(x,B) > \mbox{dist}(x,A)$. So we have that:

$(\forall a \in A)(\forall b \in B) \quad d(x,b)>d(x,a)$

Using triangle inequality we have that:
$d(x,b) < d(x,a) + d(a,b)$

So from these two inequalities we have that $(\forall a \in A)(\forall b \in B) \quad d(a,b)>0$ thus $(\forall a \in A)(\forall b \in B) \quad a \neq b$. I suppose that it is conflict, because for any $a \in A$ we have that $a=b$ where $b \in B$.

Does it work? Have you maybe any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea works. But it can also be done in a much simpler way:
$$
\mbox{dist}(x,B)=\inf\{\mbox{dist}(x,b):\ b\in B\}\leq \inf\{\mbox{dist}(x,b):\ b\in A\}=\mbox{dist}(x,A).
$$
The inequality is simply due to the fact that in the right-hand-side we are taking the infimum over a smaller set.

Comment: Of course, I understand your proof but it is only prescribing the definition of dist. Thus, is it possible to prove these inequality with infimum?

Comment: If you don't want to definition of the distance between a point and a set, how do you deduce in your proof that $\mbox{dist}(x,B)>\mbox{dist}(x,A)$ implies that $\mbox{dist}(x,b)>\mbox{dist}(x,a)$ for all $a\in A, b\in B$?